# solving an equation $x^x= c$

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving, quadratics

I would like to find a solution $x$ for $x^x = c$ where $c$ is a positive constant.

Firstly I'm looking for an approximative solution when $c$ tends to infinity.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula
$$ x = \frac{\log c}{W_k(\log c)}, k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
where $W_k$ is the $k$th branch of the product logarithm. This is the inverse of $f(x) = x^x$.

Comment: the product logarithm ? the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes. They are the same thing.

Comment: and why would you consider some particular branch of $W(z)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 The solution is not unique.

Comment: yes, we can consider the branch we'd like, that's what you meant, ok.

Comment: and wikipedia doesn't give details on the $\mathbb{Z}$ different branches (one for each solution of $z e^{z} = 1 \implies z + \ln z = 0 \implies$ one for each branch of the logarithm), how do we know what looks like the set $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ \mid \ z e^z = u \}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry, what do you mean by "what looks like"?

Comment: if I draw the set, is it on a line, a curve, doesn't it have accumulation points, does it go to $\infty$, is it contained on a half-plane, etc... ?

Comment: @user1952009 It is a countably infinite set. I don't know about the other properties though.

Comment: yes that it is (at most) countably infinite, I can prove it because $W(z)$ has as many branches as the logarithm has

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.